# Excel converting table to matrix

Tags: microsoft-excel

What would be the fastest way to create this:

[image: Desired result]

From this:

[image: Input]

Guessing combining some sort of array index with vlookup, not sure really.

Comment: Do the resulting emails have to be left-aligned?

Comment: For Person 2, do you really want the a@a.com and b@b.com emails listed out of order?

Comment: @Bandersnatch As that's the "source" table, it implies that the solution should be able to cope with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this formula: `=IF(COUNTIF($A2:$E2,J$1)=1,"x","")`

[image]

Comment: That is actually so much simpler than i thought.